# Unable to access Magento admin page

Tags: magento2, admin

I just installed Magento 2.2 on linux centos 6 with php 7.1.17 on Apache 2.4 but when I digit the url: http://localhost/Magento/admin I receive 404.

Can somebody help me ?

Comment: could you please check your app/etc/env.php and check your admin url,'backend' => [
    'frontName' => 'admin'
  ]

Comment: frontname is admin or any other value?

Comment: is a different URI assigned after the installation but even I digit it correctly I receive the same error ( 404)

Comment: Try , after flush cache

Comment: This issue happens because of 2 reasons. 1. app/etc/env.php backend URL is not admin 2. check apache httd.conf allow override is all.

Comment: I confirm the different URI in env.php that doesn't work same.

Comment: here is vhost configuiration     <Directory /var/www/html>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

Comment: please run this query and share the results
SELECT * FROM core_config_data where path LIKE "%admin/url%";

Answer (score 0):

Try hitting the url http://localhost/Magento/index.php/admin .

If it works the problem should be your .htaccess file.